# Why is Tool Options always missing in GIMP? How do I quickly get it back?

Tags: gimp

For years and across platforms every time I open GIMP the Tool Options dialog is missing.
To get it back I have to go through the menu: Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Tool Options. The dialog always opens at its smallest size and needs to be enlarged.

I cannot believe this is what everyone does. What am I doing wrong and/or how do I get it to stay across open/close?

Comment: Delete your prefs & let them rebuild. You didn't tell us what platform you're on, so we can't tell you where they might live.

Comment: This has happened on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. Where prefs live on each of these platforms can be found elsewhere on the internet.